# How to call `struct dev_archdata' function?

Tags: c, embedded

I have found a lot of questions with this error (`initializer element is not constant`) but I don't know how to adapt the answers in my code.

(I'm new in C)

I have an error with this part:

```
#include <mach/i2c.h>
#include <mach/irqs-sun7i.h>
/*
 * /////////// from mach/i2c.h //////////
struct sun7i_i2c_platform_data {
    int          bus_num;
    unsigned int frequency;
};
*/

static struct    sun7i_i2c_platform_data    sun7i_i2c_platform_data = {
    .bus_num = 1,
    .frequency = 100*1000,
};

static struct mpu_platform_data gyro_platform_data = {
    .int_config  = 0x10,
    .level_shifter = 0,
    .orientation = {  -1,  0,  0,
               0,  1,  0,
               0,  0, -1 },
    .sec_slave_type = SECONDARY_SLAVE_TYPE_COMPASS,
    .sec_slave_id   = COMPASS_ID_AK8972,
    .secondary_i2c_addr = 0x0E
};

/*
 *  /////////// from mach/i2c.h //////////
 * 
 * struct i2c_board_info {
    char        type[I2C_NAME_SIZE];
    unsigned short  flags;
    unsigned short  addr;
    void        *platform_data;
    struct dev_archdata *archdata;
    struct device_node *of_node;
    int     irq;
};*/

static struct i2c_board_info __initdata sun7i_i2c_platform_device[] = {
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("mpu6050", 0x68),
        .platform_data = &gyro_platform_data,
        .archdata = sun7i_i2c_platform_data,
    },
};
/*
// ORIGINAL //
static struct i2c_board_info __initdata single_chip_board_info[] = {
    {
        I2C_BOARD_INFO("mpu6050", 0x68),
        .irq = (IH_GPIO_BASE + MPUIRQ_GPIO),
        .platform_data = &gyro_platform_data,
    },
};
*/

static void __init sun7i_i2c_init(void)
{  
        i2c_register_board_info(2, sun7i_i2c_platform_device,
                       ARRAY_SIZE(sun7i_i2c_platform_device));
}
```

My problem come from `.archdata` init:

```
c:160:17: error: initializer element is not constant
```

I have tried with

```
.archdata = &sun7i_i2c_platform_data,
```

but in this case I have a warning and the line is ignored:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

So, how to call properly my fonction ?
Thanks

Comment: You need to explain why you want to assign an address of type `struct    sun7i_i2c_platform_data` to a pointer with type `struct dev_archdata*`. They clearly don't match.

Comment: Ah ok, thx. Because I think I need to affect a new irq adress for this device, but I don't know really how to do...

Comment: So, are the structs supposed to be compatible, or something? If so then I think you only need to silence the warning with a cast.

Comment: I don't know if it's compatible... Maybe not ! I'm trying to adapt a driver I have found on the internet ([source](http://kernel--tegra.android-source-browsing.googlecode.com/git-history/3de11fe53273ddc7bef83f013fc5c5a1fe9fb937/drivers/staging/iio/imu/inv_mpu/README?r=3de11fe53273ddc7bef83f013fc5c5a1fe9fb937))

Comment: 1) Do not use the same name for struct ... and variable. Although that works in C as struct is a seperate namespace, it is very bad practice. In general, a variable name should depict what the variable is for, not its type. 2) There seem to be much more problems. Talk to your teacher/tutor to clarify and get more background. It's not that easy just to to take something from the internet and hope it will work. You need to understand exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I'm trying to learn alone, but some subtilities escapes me... For the var name, you're right, it's a mistake I should see. Anyway, I think it's too hard for me, because I don't know really what is a bus or event irq adress - So, not easy to code in such conditions !! Thx for your advices, I will try to learn with an easier code before...

Comment: Type punning is a powerful tool, but not for beginners (it's essentially for class inheritance in a non-OO language). Definitely don't try casting pointers about until you know it's the right thing, and you know why it's the right thing (at the byte-level).